# Align calendar input and button such that their bottom are aligned

Tags: html, css

I have a calendar and a button in a row but the button is a little above the calendar. Is there a way to align the items such that their bottom matches.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="mystartDate">
        <input type="text" value="" name="startDate" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Getvalues" onclick="GetValues();" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any fiddle available?

Comment: there is no special css file

Comment: In which browser are you testing? It seems to working fine in Chrome 42. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uvyymdzr/

Comment: In firefox also working

Comment: Look lined up to me - http://jsfiddle.net/qtr5abra/1/

Comment: don't know not aligned to me in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine when you go full screen as md is for desktops. You can change your div class to `xs` in place of `md` and you will be able to see it on small screens also.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="mystartDate">
        <input type="text" value="" name="startDate" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Getvalues" onclick="GetValues();" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). The classes can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

- xs = extra small screens (mobile phones)
- md = medium screens
  (some desktops)